# Setting correct path for libraries' resources in Chrome extension

Tags: url, google-chrome-extension

If I use some external library when developing a Chrome extension, the relative paths for its resources are interpreted as relative to the current page, not the extension folder, which obviously result in a 404. Take CKEditor as an example:

```
GET http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage/config.js?t=F0RD
    ckeditor.js:77
GET http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage/skins/moono/editor.css?t=F0RD
    ckeditor.js:77
GET http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage/lang/pt-br.js?t=F0RD
    ckeditor.js:220
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined
```

What can be done to set the paths to the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "global" solution to my knowledge.

See if your library has a base bath config option. If it does not, you'll have to rewrite all paths to use `chrome.runtime.getURL()` (if possible) or a static version of that path.

---

For CKEditor in particular, this should help: [Specifying the Editor Path](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_basepath)

```
// Set this variable before loading CKEditor JS
// Replace "" with a subfolder if needed
var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = chrome.runtime.getURL("");
```